# Push data to Siri

Tags: ios, voice-recognition, siri

I know it is a long shoot but, is there any way to push data to Siri on iOS.

What I mean is, I have a program with some data like for example my shopping list or what ever. Now I would like to ask Siri what I need to buy and she would answer staff from my list.

I found that Siri don't provide API to integrate in you app but my question is vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as there is no Siri API you can't do that.

Comment: thanks, I just thought that there is a way, because weather and finance app provide answer for Siri

Comment: They're native apps, Apple does what they want ;)